# Submit form and observe the onsubmit event

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

This should be trivial, but I am not getting it :\

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform" action="#">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <a href="#" onclick="$('myform').submit()">Submit</a>
</form>
```

**JS (Prototype)**

```
$('myform').observe('submit', function(e) { 
    alert('submitted!');
    e.stop();
});
```

Why the submit is only triggered with the submit via input? Shouldn't the submit event be triggered with `$('myform').submit()` also?

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/d8BdM/

Comment: When a form is submitted by JavaScript the onsubmit event handler is never executed: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html#methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the form like this:

```
<form id="myform" action="">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub_but" />
<a href="#" onclick="$('sub_but').click();">Submit</a>
</form>
```

And keep the other code; i tested in your fiddle and works.

Saludos ;)

Comment: I put an id to the submit button...saludos ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change your javascript code like this:

```
$('myform').onsubmit = function() {
    alert('submitted!');
    return false;
};
```